# Get a value from a function in a variable in a class

Tags: php, class, variables, properties

I want to store a value in a variable (property) in a class that's returning from a function. My sample code is below-

```
<?php
class Service {
   private $opt = get_option('chaoz_opt');
}
```

But it's returing a fatal error-

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations

My expression is not allowed in this case. Is there any scope to do that? What is the right way to get the function value in a Class property (variable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the class constructor:

```
class Service {
   private $opt = null;

   public function __construct() 
   {
       $this->opt = get_option('chaoz_opt');
   }
}
```

The constructor is the first thing that will run when the class in instantiated.

**Reading Material**

[Constructors and Destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)